# Does the 'Obsession' condition mean that the character loses their 9-again ability from other sources when not pursuing their obsession?

Tags: conditions, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

The condition 'Obsession' on page 290 of my book reads as follows.

> Something’s on your character’s mind, and she just can’t shake it. If
>   she’s abiding by that obsession, exploring that emotion, or otherwise
>   pursuing the object of the obsession, enjoy the 9-again quality on all
>   rolls. When she’s not, you lose the 9-again quality.
>
> Resolution: Fulfilling the obsession, therapy.

Does the wording of 'you lose the 9-again quality' mean that other sources of 9-again, like the two-dot bonus from the Professional Training merit, are no longer applicable until the condition is shed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be correct. The assumption would be this specific rule from the condition is going to override any other factors that might give you a boost with 9-again. The only things you will have 9-again on will be tasks associated with pursuing your obsession.

That is the intended penalty of this condition. While you can laser focus in on any task that relates to your obsession, you are unable to gain such benefits to anything unrelated.

Until your character can resolve this obsession in some way, either through finding a sense of completion with the obsession or therapy, you are held back by your inner voice reminding you constantly about how you should be focused on nothing but the thing that is driving your obsession.